# How to Change button Class on Click

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have 2 buttons & I want to show **active button** by changing button class. I am trying to do by removeClass && addClass. Getting error

> removeClass is not a function

.component.html

```
<div class="col" id="but">
  <button #draw id="draw" class="btn btn-success" (click)="DrawSketch(draw)">Draw Sketch</button>

  <button #upload id="upload" class="btn bg-gradient-white" (click)="UploadSketch(upload)">Upload Sketch</button>
</div>

<div>{{activeButton}}</div>
```

.component.ts

```
  uploadId: any;
  drawId: any;
  activeButton:string;

  DrawSketch(button){
    this.drawId = button.id;
    console.log("DrawSketch called...",this.drawId);   
    this.drawId.removeClass('bg-gradient-white').addClass('btn-success');
    this.uploadId.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('bg-gradient-white');
    this.activeButton = "Draw";
  }

  UploadSketch(button){
    this.uploadId = button.id;
    console.log("UploadSketch called...", this.uploadId);
    this.uploadId.removeClass('bg-gradient-white').addClass('btn-success');
    this.drawId.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('bg-gradient-white');
    this.activeButton = "Upload";
  }
```

Here is [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter).

How to do this? Where am i doing wrong?

please suggest if there is any better/other way.

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-success" [class.active]="someProperty">`

Comment: ```<button class="btn btn-success" [class.active]="btn-success" (click)="DrawSketch()">Draw Sketch</button>

  <button class="btn bg-gradient-white" [class.active]="btn-success" (click)="UploadSketch()">Upload Sketch</button>``` Do you mean like this?

Comment: No. The value is an expression, and when it's truthy the class is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of ngClass to dynamically add or remove classes.

**in .component.ts**

```
   uploadId: any;
  drawId: any;
  activeButton:string = 'Draw'; // Set the draw button by default as activeButton

  DrawSketch(button){
    this.drawId = button.id;
    console.log("DrawSketch called...",this.drawId);   
    this.activeButton = "Draw";
  }

  UploadSketch(button){
    this.uploadId = button.id;
    console.log("UploadSketch called...", this.uploadId);
    this.activeButton = "Upload";
  }
```

**in .component.html**

```
<div class="col" id="but">
  <button #draw id="draw" class="btn" [ngClass]="{ 'btn-success': activeButton === 'Draw', 'bg-gradient-white': activeButton !== 'Draw'}" (click)="DrawSketch(draw)">Draw Sketch</button>

  <button #upload id="upload" class="btn" [ngClass]="{ 'btn-success': activeButton === 'Upload', 'bg-gradient-white': activeButton !== 'Upload'}" (click)="UploadSketch(upload)">Upload Sketch</button>
</div>

<div>{{activeButton}}</div>
```

Comment: button color is not changing

Comment: Can you check (in the console of the browser) which classes are set on your buttons & if they are changing when you are clicking them ? In case you copied from my answer, I just saw I made a typo in my class 'btn-succes' (should be 'btn-success'). I will edit this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I have a [link](https://appdividend.com/2019/02/07/angular-7-ngclass-tutorial-with-example-angular-ngclass/) which you can use if you needed to change css. For example if I needed to apply different css classes on button based a certain condition, I will do something like this:

```
    <button [ngClass]="{
    'removeClass':Condition === '1stOption',
    'addClass':Condition === '2ndOption',
    'defaultClass':Condition === 'defaultOption'
  }"> Button content </button>
```

I hope it helps...
Check the working here: [Working Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqewqh)

Comment: I want to show one active button at a time. so if one button is active its color will be up if not it will be in white background color.